# Why is my UINavigation controller off by 79 pixels

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

In the iphone everything works great.

However when I look at my navigationbar frame it is -44?  Iphone the y origin is 0.

Is it supposed to be this?  Now everything seems to be shifted up by 79 pixels.

Any idea how to fix?

When I rotate everything sizes ok it is just the initial landscape size that is wrong.

adding to the view this code fixes it but is obviously not what I want to do:         navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(-79, 0, size.width, size.height);

```
StarTravelAppDelegate *appDelegate = (StarTravelAppDelegate *)
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    FirstMenuView *firstMenuView = [[[FirstMenuView alloc] init] autorelease];

   // bac123ViewController *bac123 = [[bac123ViewController alloc] autorelease];

   // UINavigationController *navigationController;
   // appDelegate.navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstMenuView] autorelease];

    MyNavigationController *navigationController = appDelegate.navController;
    [navigationController pushViewController:firstMenuView animated:true];

    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(-79, 0, size.width, size.height);

   // UIView *view = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view];

   // [view addSubview:bac123.view];


 //  [view addSubview:navigationController.view];
    navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true;
```

The app delegate:

```
@implementation MyNavigationController


// The available orientations should be defined in the Info.plist file.
// And in iOS 6+ only, you can override it in the Root View controller in the "supportedInterfaceOrientations" method.
// Only valid for iOS 6+. NOT VALID for iOS 4 / 5.
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    // iPhone only
    if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

    // iPad only
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

// Supported orientations. Customize it for your own needs
// Only valid on iOS 4 / 5. NOT VALID for iOS 6.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // iPhone only
    if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone )
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);

    // iPad only
    // iPhone only
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

// This is needed for iOS4 and iOS5 in order to ensure
// that the 1st scene has the correct dimensions
// This is not needed on iOS6 and could be added to the application:didFinish...
-(void) directorDidReshapeProjection:(CCDirector*)director
{
    if(director.runningScene == nil) {
        // Add the first scene to the stack. The director will draw it immediately into the framebuffer. (Animation is started automatically when the view is displayed.)
        // and add the scene to the stack. The director will run it when it automatically when the view is displayed.
        [director runWithScene: [SpaceScene scene]];
    }
}
@end


@implementation StarTravelAppDelegate

@synthesize window=window_, navController=navController_, director=director_;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create the main window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    // CCGLView creation
    // viewWithFrame: size of the OpenGL view. For full screen use [_window bounds]
    //  - Possible values: any CGRect
    // pixelFormat: Format of the render buffer. Use RGBA8 for better color precision (eg: gradients). But it takes more memory and it is slower
    //  - Possible values: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
    // depthFormat: Use stencil if you plan to use CCClippingNode. Use Depth if you plan to use 3D effects, like CCCamera or CCNode#vertexZ
    //  - Possible values: 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES
    // sharegroup: OpenGL sharegroup. Useful if you want to share the same OpenGL context between different threads
    //  - Possible values: nil, or any valid EAGLSharegroup group
    // multiSampling: Whether or not to enable multisampling
    //  - Possible values: YES, NO
    // numberOfSamples: Only valid if multisampling is enabled
    //  - Possible values: 0 to glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_SAMPLES_APPLE)
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                   depthFormat:0
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];



    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Display FSP and SPF
    [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

    // set FPS at 60
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director_ setView:glView];

    // 2D projection
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
    //  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change this setting at any time.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    // If the 1st suffix is not found and if fallback is enabled then fallback suffixes are going to searched. If none is found, it will try with the name without suffix.
    // On iPad HD  : "-ipadhd", "-ipad",  "-hd"
    // On iPad     : "-ipad", "-hd"
    // On iPhone HD: "-hd"
    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

    // Create a Navigation Controller with the Director
    navController_ = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
    navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;


    // for rotation and other messages
    [director_ setDelegate:navController_];

    // set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
    [window_ setRootViewController:navController_];
    //[window_ addSubview: navController_.view];

    // make main window visible
    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];



    return YES;
}

// getting a call, pause the game
-(void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ pause];
}

// call got rejected
-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNextDeltaTimeZero:YES];
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ resume];
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ startAnimation];
}

// application will be killed
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    CC_DIRECTOR_END();
}

// purge memory
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
}

// next delta time will be zero
-(void) applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNextDeltaTimeZero:YES];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [window_ release];
    [navController_ release];

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: code.... have you seen ur nib file ?

Comment: The nib files are sometimes represented as 4'' where as the default simulator is a 3.5'' device, I noticed this when laying items in interface builder... if it's not this, just post some code printing your NavControllers frame.

Comment: I am simulating an iPad.  It only happens for the iPad simulator